# ASP.NET Core 3.1 Certificate Authentication in IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, authentication, certificate

I am trying to use certificate authentication with ASP.NET Core 3.1. I will be hosting WebAPI in IIS using inprocess model. I looked at the sample code from official docs and tried doing the POC.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/certauth?view=aspnetcore-3.1

But I am not able to test it out. I have tried it with default certificate as well as custom certificate. I have added the certificate to Personal store. Run netsh commands to add ssl binding using this certificate thumbprint. When I launch the app in debug mode, I can see the site being protected by the appropriate certificate.

However, if I add [Authorize] to individual controller action method or at Controller level, I get 403 error. But I dont see the validate certificate method being triggered. So unable to identify what is the root cause. Please let me know if anyone has a working sample that I could refer to.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using http or https (secure)?  Https uses TLS for authentication along with a certificate.  TLS is performed before the http request is sent out and if fails you would not get the response error 403.  So it look like you are sending http (should be sending https) and the server is refusing a non secure connection.

Comment: yes. I am using https. I initially tried with postman and calls were failing. Now going to try with standalone console app.

Comment: It looks like the TLS is passing since you are getting a 403 response.  If TLS was failing you would not get any response.  So the authorization is a 2nd level login type authentication that is failing.